# IT Software Asset and Architecture Catalog

Tags: web-apps, asset-management

I work in an IT department for an medium sized (2,000) organisation and am looking for some help with managing our bespoke and third party applications.

I'm looking for a web based SaaS software that I can use to catalog our software systems and related infrastructure.   This includes software with custom attributes (e.g. business owner, language written in, TCP ports used), databases with attributes, servers with attributes, and people.  We would also want to link all those assets together (this application uses this server).

We should then be able to do a relational lookup to see what affects what - if I took down this server, which applications/databases would be affected.

We don't want/need auto-discovery, happy for manual input.

Nice to haves would include: federated auth, uploading images/PDFs (e.g. architecture diagrams), WIKI pages for notes/troubleshooting, auto-generated diagrams showing things linking together for a holistic map.

I'm happy to pay up to a few thousand a month for the solution.

Thanks for reading this far. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Clappia](https://www.clappia.com?it-software-asset-and-architecture-catalog). Clappia is a cloud-based platform that you can use to design custom apps within minutes, and without writing any code. I tried to create the following two inter-connected apps, one for maintaining server details, and another for tracking application details along with the server that it is using.

**App to track Server details**

[image: Server App]

**Data in the server app**: I submitted some dummy entries into this app, which looks like this.

[image: Server app submissions]

**App to track applications**: Now I created a new app which is inter-connected to the first app, i.e., the data entered in the first app is available in this app.

[image]

**Filters/queries**: You can now view the submissions in the second application to look at all the applications along with their server details. If you want to search all applications using a server, a filter on Server Name can also be applied (although not visible in the screenshot below).

[image: App submissions]

- All attributes in these apps are totally configurable. You can add any number of additional attributes you want, without writing any code.
- Similar to these apps, any number of additional apps can also be created to track databases with their custom attributes, people, etc.
- Clappia has a permission model using which you can restrict access to apps to selected users. All users will have their own logins and can view only the data for apps they are allowed to view.
- All apps can support file attachments and links to other websites.
- Auto-generated diagrams/maps are not supported.

Disclosure: I am associated with Clappia.